# AllFileSelector. How exclude the current directory

Tags: java, apache-commons-vfs

With this lines I'm get a list with all files under but also the current directory

```
List<FileObject> fileList = new ArrayList<FileObject>();
FileObject fileObject = ...
fileObject.findFiles(new AllFileSelector(), depthwise, fileList);
```

the list content it:

```
/foo/boo/bla.jpg
/foo/tal.jpg
/foo/cheese.jpg
/foo
```

and I want to get just this:

```
/foo/boo/bla.jpg
/foo/tal.jpg
/foo/cheese.jpg
```

have I set something in the selector?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [FileTypeSelector](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/FileTypeSelector.html) or implement your own [FileSelector](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/FileSelector.html).

```
fileObject.findFiles(new FileTypeSelector(FileType.FILE), depthwise, fileList);
```

This example will only select files and not directories. This might be sufficient for your current problem, but if you want to filter files based on their extension, e.g. ".png", then you must implement your own [org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileFilter](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/FileFilter.html) and use a [FileFilterSelector](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/FileFilterSelector.html).